# How to provide power to a device that needs 3 different input voltages?

Tags: power-supply

I have a device with 3 different modules that require different input voltages: 2 V, 5 V, and 30 V. The 2 V supply needs to be electrically isolated from the others. What would be the simplest way to provide the 3 different voltages?

I've been considering using 3 different AC/DC switching power supplies or somehow using a single power supply and splitting the output voltage. I'm having trouble finding inexpensive (less than $100) power supplies that can output 2 V or 30 V which leads me to think that most people must be doing something more customized when they need these voltages. According to the specs of my device, the ripple for each of these voltages should be less than 200 mV. The maximum current for the modules doesn't need to be more than 1 A.

Edit: There is no sequencing requirement for the different voltages. The typical currents are as follows: 1 A (for 2 V), 0.2 A (for 5 V), and 0.01 A (for 30 V). The specific device is a single photon counting module (SPCM-AQ4C Excelitas). Since this is for sensitive measurements, the power supplies should be well-regulated and low-noise. Also, the device will be using mains supply not battery.

Comment: I may provide a better answer later. But often, devices which use more than one Voltage have a sequencing requirement for the different voltages. In other words, sometimes one must come up before the others. You should look into that. May effect the answer. You should also list current for each voltage.  Most likely the best thing would be to supply 30V, and use small DC-DC converters to get 5V and 2V. But if the 30V requirement is very low, you can maybe generate it with a little charge pump supply.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll add some more info to my post.

Comment: Can you provide information about the 'device' in your application?

Comment: Sure! I have added to my edits to specify the device.

Comment: I have a Rigol DP832 that seems like it should do that. It seems weird to use an adjustable bench supply for something like this though.

Comment: The device will be battery powered or mains? Thus detail will greatly change the efficiency required for the power supplies...

Comment: It will use mains supply. I'll add this info above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add up units cost for the following four power supplies, it just meets your budget (Digikey prices for quality units). This approach is to convert mains into an intermediate voltage with an AC-DC converter and then convert up or down to the required voltages with DC-DC converters.

1. mains to 24V 25W        $19
2. 24 to 1.8~3.6V at 8A    $54  (isolated)
3. 24 to 5V @ 2A           $14
4. 24 to +/-15V (30V)      $13  (isolated)

Try doing a parametric search and see what you can find. I notice the maximum draws for your unit are specified as 3A at 2V and 1A at 5V and only 40mA from the 30V.

Note that cheaper DC-DC converters may go out of regulation unless you give them a minimum load, and some DC-DC converters are not regulated at all.